# Mimicking Visual Studio "Properties" Tab in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ide

I'm creating a simple WYSIWYG editor for HTML in C#, and I want to implement a simple group of controls to view and manipulate the various properties of HTML form elements. I envision the properties panel to look like the one in Visual Studio:

[image: Picture of the properties box in visual studio]

Such that when the user clicks on an HTML element they've added they can change the text, class, id, etc. of the element. The problem is, I can't find how to make a panel that looks like this using C#. Obviously I know how to implement the dropdown list and the buttons, but the main body that actually contains the properties is like a slick version of a tree-view that I don't even know where to begin coding.

I'm not looking for someone to code this whole thing for me, but it would be great if somebody could point me to a form control that looks like the tree-view. I have tried googling around for answers but haven't had any luck. I have also tried looking at the open source project [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) which uses a similar control, but I've had considerable trouble wading through the hundreds of files of code to find the specific part of the GUI I'm focused on.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Sorry if I was a tad bit vauge above, I guess what I'm really looking for is a nice form control or set of controls in C# to mimick the main body of the properties window. I've tried to be as thorough as possible, but if you have any questions leave a comment and I'll try to improve my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body of that panel contains a PropertyGrid control, which you can use yourself.  It's not in the Toolbox by default but you can add it.